# Удаление разделов сайта в URL-адресах регулярными выражениями

Tags: регулярные-выражения, url

Как настроить обработку адресов, чтобы URL вида `/catalog/razdel/element/` менялись на `/razdel/element/`?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/zO2xE4/2 — это Вам нужно?

Comment: да, спасибо, пригодилось

Comment: Подсократил — https://regex101.com/r/zO2xE4/5 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помогает разбиение модели на подвыражения, заключённые в круглые скобки — `()` . Положим, адрес сайта — `http://SashaGoddess.com`. Попробуем следующий шаблон:

*Поиск*: `(http:\/\/SashaGoddess\.com\/)(.*?\/)(.*?\/.*?\/)`
*Замена*: `$1$3`
*Демонстрация*: https://regex101.com/r/lR5pJ1/1

Разберём его:

- В первых круглых скобках содержится имя сайта,
- Во вторых — первый его раздел, т. е. текст, ограниченный спереди и сзади прямыми слэшами — `/`,
- В третьих — 2 последующих раздела сайта.
- `$1$3` означает, что будет произведена замена на содержимое внутри первых и третьих скобок. То, что находится внутри вторых, удалится. В зависимости от реализации регулярных выражений вместо метасимвола `$` может использоваться `\`.

В итоге адрес `http://SashaGoddess.com/catalog/razdel/element/` заменится на `http://SashaGoddess.com/razdel/element/`.

Данным паттерном удалятся названия любых разделов в корневой папке сайта. Например, как видно из примера, адрес `http://SashaGoddess.com/Dream/Miracle/Destiny/` обратится в `http://SashaGoddess.com/Miracle/Destiny/`. Если в URL необходимо избавиться только от следующего за именем сайта раздела `catalog`, модифицируем выражение:

*Поиск*: `(http:\/\/SashaGoddess\.com\/)(catalog\/)(.*?\/.*?\/)`
*Замена*: `$1$3`
*Демонстрация*: https://regex101.com/r/lR5pJ1/2

В сравнении с прошлой моделью вместо метасимволов `.*?` (любые символы кроме переноса строки, повторённые 0 или более раз, включён ленивый режим) появились литералы `catalog`. Произведётся замена `http://SashaGoddess.com/catalog/razdel/element/` → `http://SashaGoddess.com/razdel/element/`, а URL, где первый раздел не называется `catalog`, как то `http://SashaGoddess.com/Dream/Miracle/Destiny/` останутся прежними.